# Getting rural/urban classification from Zip Codes

Tags: openstreetmap, classification, population, demography, regionalization

I have a dataset containing GPS coordinates and zip codes of locations from different regions in Spain, and I need to classify them as rural or urban based on either of these two information sets (and additionally having the city/town names based on these two).

I was wondering if anyone knows if there is any mapping (from zip codes or area names to rural/urban) I can find from a known, credible source, or if there is a way to classify these locations as rural or urban on my own if I have coordinates and/or zip codes?

Maybe if anyone can point me to a source that describes how this type of classification is typically done. For example, over here there is a mention of the classification that EU uses to classify as `'predominantly urban'`, `'predominantly rural'` and `'intermediate'`, but is there a simpler method?

Answer (score 2):

There’s two parts to this.. assuming you have the coordinates (lat/lon)

**Urban Classification**

For something like this you might want to take a look at [Corine Land Classification](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/copernicus-land-monitoring-service-corine). This is a raster with a series of classifications (Dense Urban, Light Urban, Farmland, Vineyard, Water, Peat Bog…).

It’s then a matter of doing a point-to-raster sampling. You don’t mention which tools you have available, but in QGIS you could use the **Point Sampling** plugin. Other GIS tools should have equivalent functionality.

For an example, have a look at the [recent work done by Alasdair Rae](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/news/nr/land-cover-atlas-uk-1.744440), it was done for the UK but the raster covers the whole of the EU.

For a coarse urban/rural classification, you could also look at [NaturalEarthData urban areas layer](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/).

**Finding place names**

Take a look at [Who’s on first](https://mapzen.com/blog/who-s-on-first/) from Mapzen. This is web API for geolocating points to the correct urban footprint